# Are there any rules about quotes in JSON strings?

Tags: javascript, json

What do you think is a correct JSON string?

Some of the JSON visualization WEB tools that i use(such as http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm) says that strings in JSON should be wrapped in double quotes.

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to find a rule or any kind of information that proofs this statement as correct but without success.

As we all know javascript does not care what kind of a quotes we use for strings (single or double) then why there is a rule in JSON's ??
I use JSON's alot and never had any problems in browsers caused by this rule.

If any of you knows why is this statement true please share it.
I will be very grateful.

Тhanks!

Answer (score 6):

> What do you think is a correct JSON string?

spec is here :

http://www.json.org/

spec says strings are quoted with double quotes, end of story.

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in
>   double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as
>   a single character string.

Comment: Why does the browser not care if you are using signle quotes instaed doubles? If there is no problem with single quotes than in JavaScript this rule is not valid.

Comment: because JSON is not javascript,it's kind of a subset of javascript.When you're writing javascript objects you are not writing JSON ,JSON is a serialization format,like XML.

Comment: So, `JSON` is a subset of `JavaScript` in which string is wrapped in double quotes to be valid, but the `JavaScript` allows us to use single qutoes. The "dobule qutoes" rule may be valid in 1999, but in our days it is meaningless.

Comment: JSON is a spec for a serialization format,the only thing that matters is that JSON serializers and deserializers agree on a same spec,wether they are written in Java,C++ or Ruby. JSON spec is not a matter of opinion.A spec has to be respected,period.

Comment: Yes I completely agree with you in case we were living in a percfect world and we are not. As browsers do not care if you are missing the `;` at the end of the line or you are using `'` intead of `"` (and they will probably never care) this rule is meaningless.

Comment: Give me an example when using `"` will give me something more than `'` and I will agree there is difference (in the scope of JavaScript - not Ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Just for a quick help over here, i think you must use double quotes.
Use " instead of '

```
{"Test":"1"}
```